# What's the difference between access_control and public_read_access for S3 AWS CDK?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I'm super new to CDK and I'm wondering what the difference is between the following options:

```
access_control=s3.BucketAccessControl("PUBLIC_READ")
```

VS

```
public_read_access=True
```

Is using both options redundant?

```
site_bucket = s3.Bucket(
        self, 
        "site-bucket",
        access_control=s3.BucketAccessControl("PUBLIC_READ"),
        public_read_access=True,
        website_index_document="index.html",
        versioned=True,
        removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        auto_delete_objects=True
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`access_control` applies a [canned ACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) to the bucket.

`public_read_access=True` is the same as calling `site_bucket.grant_public_access()`. Updates the bucket policy to [allow any principal to read objects in the bucket](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/7d2684edc67b6fc4ea957e1a2a44d726c08e4047/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-s3/lib/bucket.ts#L676).